# Why does easy_install [sic] for buildbot throw an error for python.h in gcc?

Tags: python, gcc, buildbot

```
Searching for twisted>=9.0.0
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/twisted/
Best match: Twisted 13.1.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/T/Twisted/Twisted-13.1.0.tar.bz2#md5=5609c91ed465f5a7da48d30a0e7b6960
Processing Twisted-13.1.0.tar.bz2
Running Twisted-13.1.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-ZqKkRp/Twisted-13.1.0/egg-dist-tmp-rxcZGJ
twisted/runner/portmap.c:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

So much for "easy"

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: FWIW, you should probably use `pip` for a variety of reasons. It doesn't solve this particular problem (that's hard to do without being the distro package manager), but it solves others.